# What are some factors affecting the rate of cooling of a liquid?

Tags: thermodynamics, cooling

What are possible factors affecting the rate of cooling of a liquid, aside from the volume of water, surface area of the water, or type of container.

Comment: Are there any other restrictions on what can be done?  This seems far too broad to me.

Comment: this is it... no more restrictions other than the fact that the liquid is water and that the equipment needed shouldn't be too complex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the liquid is water, then for your purposes the things controlling the rate of cooling would be as follows:

1) the thermal conductivity of the material from which the water container is made. if the container is *copper*, for example, then the water will cool a lot faster than if the container were plastic.

2) the thickness of the container walls; thinner means faster heat loss.

3) the ambient temperature of your laboratory. the colder the lab, the faster the water will lose its heat.

4) whether or not you stir the water. *gentle* stirring will enhance heat loss.

5) whether or not you blow air over the container during the experiment, since fan-driven convective heat loss will be faster than conductive heat loss into the ambient air.

AND...

6) *If the container is open to the air:* cooling by evaporation will also occur, if the humidity is low. In this case, then, the ambient humidity will affect the cooldown rate.

Comment: if so- you can "check" the answer as "accepted". Best regards, Niels

Comment: Add evaporation. Which also depends on humidity.

Comment: thanks, will edit (i assumed the container was not open)

Comment: Is the container completely full, or is the liquid level somewhat below the lip of the container?  If air is blowing horizontally across the container, the evaporation rate should be affected by the liquid depth in the container.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the geometry and all the adimensional variables associated with the fluid: Reynolds, Prandtl, Brickman and Nusselt typically. They compare viscuous and kinetic terms in the NS equation. The adimensional temperature equation becomes: $\frac{dT}{dt} = \frac{Br}{Re Pr} \varphi + \frac{1}{Re Pr} \Delta T$ for a Newtownian fluid in an instationary flow.

Comment: Thanks bro, but I'm in high school. I haven't even done calculus yet but I want to learn, if anybody here wants to teach me

Answer (score 0):

High school student answers (probably an investigation):

- surrounding room temperature
- type of fluid, water, milk etc
- material of the container
- if enclosed or open container
- if the fluid is moved, stirred
- the amount of fluid